# Using UEye API in Python

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv, camera

I am currently working on a project that involves attaching an IDS UEye XC camera to a Raspberry Pi 3 to record video. I wrote one script (script 1) using C++, OpenCV, and the IDS API and another script (script 2) in Python to launch and stop script 1 using the GPIO buttons on the Raspberry Pi. Attached are scripts 1 and 2.

Script 1:

```
#include "uEye.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

HIDS hCam = 1;
SENSORINFO sensor_info;
CAMINFO camera_info;
int nRet;
int Mode;
char strCamFileName[256];
int img_width=640;
int img_height=480;

int main ()
{
//initialize camera
nRet = is_InitCamera(&hCam, NULL);
cout << "Status Init: " << nRet << endl;

//get sensor info
//nRet = is_GetSensorInfo(hCam, &sensor_info);
//cout << "Sensor Color Mode: " << sensor_info.nColorMode << endl;
//cout << "Camera Model: " << sensor_info.strSensorName << endl;

//get camera info
//nRet = is_GetCameraInfo(hCam, &camera_info);
//cout << "Camera ID: " << camera_info.ID << endl;
//cout << "Camera SerNum: " << camera_info.SerNo << endl;
//cout << "Camera Version: " << camera_info.Version << endl;
//cout << "Camera Type: " << camera_info.Type << endl;

//color mode
Mode = IS_CM_RGB8_PACKED;
nRet = is_SetColorMode(hCam, Mode);
cout << "Color Mode: " << nRet << endl;

UINT formatID = 13;
nRet = is_ImageFormat(hCam, IMGFRMT_CMD_SET_FORMAT, &formatID, 4);
cout << "Status Image Format: " << nRet << endl;

char* pMem = NULL;
int memID = 0;
nRet = is_AllocImageMem(hCam, img_width, img_height, 24, &pMem, &memID);
nRet = is_SetImageMem(hCam, pMem, memID);

//set display mode
Mode = IS_SET_DM_DIB;
nRet = is_SetDisplayMode(hCam, Mode);

//zoom
double dZoomValue = 0;
nRet = is_Zoom(hCam, ZOOM_CMD_DIGITAL_SET_VALUE, (void*)&dZoomValue, sizeof(dZoomValue));
cout << "Zoom: " << dZoomValue << endl;

VideoWriter video("out.avi", CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 10, Size(img_width, img_height),true);

for(int ii=0; ii<600; ii++)
{
   if(is_FreezeVideo(hCam, IS_WAIT) == IS_SUCCESS){
        void *pMemVoid; //pointer to where the image is stored
        is_GetImageMem (hCam, &pMemVoid);
        Mat img=Mat(Size(img_width,img_height), CV_8UC3, pMemVoid);
    video.write(img);
    namedWindow( "Live Video", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    resizeWindow("Live Video", 320,240);
    imshow("Live Video", img);
    waitKey(1);

   }
}
//exit camera
is_ExitCamera(hCam);

return 0;
}
```

Script 2:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import signal
import time
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import sys
from sys import exit

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

set = 0
while True:
    if GPIO.input(12) == False and set == 0:
        print('Starting Video Recording')
        p=subprocess.Popen("./video", shell=False, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        time.sleep(1)
        set = 1
    if GPIO.input(16) == False and set == 1:
        print('Stopping Video Recording')
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        time.sleep(2)
        set = 0
    if GPIO.input(18) == False and set == 0:
        print('Exit Video Recording') 
        time.sleep(1)
        break
GPIO.cleanup()
```

I thought everything was working perfectly until I tried to transfer the video files from the Raspberry to a Windows 7 laptop. I found that if I let script 1 run for its entire duration uninterrupted that it would play on the laptop but if I interrupted script 1 using script 2 and then tried to play it on the laptop it wouldn't render.

This lead me to believe that the camera wasn't "cleaning up" properly when I interrupted it. What I mean by that is it doesn't get to `is_ExitCamera()` which cleanly releases and closes the camera. I am currently killing the program using `os.killpg()`. Is there a way to replace that with `is_ExitCamera()` somehow even though one is C++ and the other is Python?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the uEye API in python by calling all of the functions with "ctypes". I'm not sure whether you could call just the is_exitCamera command in the second script, or whether you will need to re-write all of the first c++ script as python.

**example of uEye API in python using ctypes:**

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

uEyeDll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("ueye_api.dll") #include full path or copy dll into same folder as .py script


#connect camera
cam = ctypes.c_uint32(0)
hWnd = ctypes.c_voidp()
msg=uEyeDll.is_InitCamera(ctypes.byref(cam),hWnd)
ErrChk=uEyeDll.is_EnableAutoExit (cam, ctypes.c_uint(1))
if ~ErrChk:
    print (' Camera Connected')
IS_CM_SENSOR_RAW8  =ctypes.c_int(11)
nRet = uEyeDll.is_SetColorMode(cam,IS_CM_SENSOR_RAW8)
IS_SET_TRIGGER_SOFTWARE = ctypes.c_uint(0x1000)
nRet = uEyeDll.is_SetExternalTrigger(cam, IS_SET_TRIGGER_SOFTWARE)


#allocate memory
width_py = 1600
height_py = 1200
pixels_py =8

width = ctypes.c_int(width_py) #convert python values into c++ integers
height = ctypes.c_int(height_py) 
bitspixel=ctypes.c_int(pixels_py)
pcImgMem = ctypes.c_char_p() #create placeholder for image memory
pid=ctypes.c_int()

ErrChk=uEyeDll.is_AllocImageMem(cam, width, height,  bitspixel, ctypes.byref(pcImgMem), ctypes.byref(pid))


# Get image data    
uEyeDll.is_SetImageMem(cam, pcImgMem, pid)
ImageData = np.ones((height_py,width_py),dtype=np.uint8)

#put these lines inside a while loop to return continuous images to the array "ImageData"  
uEyeDll.is_FreezeVideo (cam, ctypes.c_int(0x0000))  #IS_DONT_WAIT  = 0x0000, or IS_GET_LIVE = 0x8000
uEyeDll.is_CopyImageMem (cam, pcImgMem, pid, ImageData.ctypes.data)
```